# I am unable to view attributes of a graph read from a GML file in python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx, digraphs

I am trying to use the networkx package to work on a directed graph. The file was read successfully but a lot of the functions do not give any output for it.

```
import networkx as nx
MyGraph=nx.DiGraph()
MyGraph=nx.read_gml("celegansneural.gml")
MyGraph.degree()
```

I get the following output:

```
DiDegreeView({})
```

similarly for `MyGraph.edges()`
the output I get is []

How do I work with the file?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with your code.  Are you sure that the file has data in it?  Could you open it in a text editor and see what the contents look like?  There should be data formatted [like this](https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/gml-format/).

Comment: Yes, I checked and the file does have data in the given format

Comment: Could you post the file possibly?  What version of networkx are you using?